# Compare value in the same column in R

Tags: r

I want to compare the values in the same column in R.
My data set is like :

F1      F2      F3
C300100 M1001   abc
C300100 M1002   abc,def
C300100 M1003   abc,def,ghi
C300101 M1004   q
C300101 M1005   q,r
C300101 M1006   q,r,s
C300101 M1007   a,b,c,d
C30010111   C300101 abc
C30010111   C300101 def,khy
C30010199   cc  c23

The expected output is :

F1     F2    F3             F4
C300100    M1001    abc        TRUE
C300100    M1002    abc,def    TRUE
C300100    M1003    abc,def,ghi TRUE
C300101     M1004   q           TRUE
C300101     M1005   q,r         TRUE
C300101     M1006   q,r,s       TRUE
C300101     M1007   a,b,c,d      FALSE
C30010111   M1008   abc         FALSE
C30010111   C300101 def,khy     FALSE
C30010199   cc  c23             FALSE

In the first case of F1= A  and F2 = 100, because F3=g is present in second record and third record so it is true.

For the second record A    100  g,h   g and h is present in record 3 so it is true.

I need to compare first record with second and third and so on,
then second record with third and so on.
If value is present is subsequent record then it is TRUE otherwise it is FALSE.

is there a library and function which does this efficiently.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this base R approach :

```
df$result <- unlist(sapply(split(df, df$F1), function(x) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  tmp <- strsplit(x$F3, ',')
  sapply(seq_len(n), function(x) all(sapply(tmp[min(x+1, n):n], 
                                            function(y) all(tmp[[x]] %in% y))))
}))

df

#         F1    F2          F3 result
#1   C300100 M1001         abc   TRUE
#2   C300100 M1002     abc,def   TRUE
#3   C300100 M1003 abc,def,ghi   TRUE
#4   C300101 M1004           q   TRUE
#5   C300101 M1005         q,r   TRUE
#6   C300101 M1006       q,r,s   TRUE
#7 C30010111 M1007     g,h,I,j  FALSE
#8 C30010111 M1008         abc   TRUE
#9 C30010199 M1009         c23   TRUE
```

Comment: some issues with whole dataset

Comment: @user13472171 The last value in each group (`F1`) should always be true right? Can you check if the updated answer is closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that all the letters are sorted and separated by a comma and space, then You could do:

```
df$F4 <-  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) all(grepl(df$F3[x], tail(df$F3,-x))))
df
  F1  F2    F3   F4
1  A 100     a TRUE
2  A 100   a,b TRUE
3  A 100 a,b,c TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate(F4 =  str_detect(F3, lag(F3, default = first(F3))))
#   F1  F2    F3   F4
# 1  A 100     a TRUE
# 2  A 100   a,b TRUE
# 3  A 100 a,b,c TRUE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(F1 = c("A", "A", "A"), F2 = c(100L, 100L, 100L
), F3 = c("a", "a,b", "a,b,c")), 
   row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, with this first value is always true. If we look at the this table   :F1 F2 F3  
C300100 M1001 abc  
C300100 M1002 abc,def  
C300100 M1003 abc,def,ghi  
C300101 M1004 q
C300101 M1005 q,r
C300101 M1006 q,r,s
C300101 M1007 a,b,c,d  
C30010111 C300101 abc  
C30010111 C300101 def,khy  
C30010199 cc c23 df %>% group_by(F1)%>%
  mutate(F4 =  str_detect(F3, lag(F3, default = first(F3))))